# google-services plugin could not detect any version for com.google.android.gms or com.google.firebase, default version: 9.0.0 will be used

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, gradle-plugin

I am integrating fire-base to my existing project used these libs

```
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
```

Dependencies

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

I am getting this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
```

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

Not able to figure out what is happening ??

These are my play services verison
 [image]

Comment: In which file do you've added the dependencies-classpath? it should be inside the "build.gradle" in the root folder.
Additionally have a look at the gardle version. I've used 2.13.

Comment: dependencies-classpath are in proper file because i am running this project since last 8 months. Whenever we decided to move on firebase and changed the palysevices version, these problem started appearing

Comment: Have you added the "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" in gradle.build? I've used this [tutorial](http://shubhank101.github.io/iOSAndroidChaosOverFlow/2016/06/Implementing-FCM-(-Firebase-Cloud-Messaging-)-in-Android-App)

Comment: yes I have added that apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Answer (score 7):

I have added this line at last in build.gradle:(Module: app)

```
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and it started working I don't know what is concept behind this?
but it is working

Comment: Ty. I had it on the top migrating from GCM and was banging my head 2 hours why it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default selection via the gradle file, and by doing so avoid collision between the RA project and your client one: [Duplicate entry: com/google/firebase/FirebaseApiNotAvailableException.class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38595171/606351)