# Duplicate entry: com/google/firebase/FirebaseApiNotAvailableException.class

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I have an Android project built with React-Native and employing Google Play Services (analytics, cloud messaging, ads). I'm not explicitly using Firebase anywhere.

Tried upgrading the Play Services from 8.4.0 => 9.2.0. Also upgraded the GPS classpath.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

...

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1'
```

Notice that I'm not explicitly depending on Firebase anywhere.

Ever since the upgrade I'm getting the following Gradle build error:

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/firebase/FirebaseApiNotAvailableException.class

I know that Firebase comes bundled within the Google Play Services ([since 9.0](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)), so I figured something else is compiling and linking with an older version.
So looking at the dependency insight (`gradle -q dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency firebase`) I've noticed that firebase-common 9.0.0 is being added on top of 9.2.1:

[image]

But I can't for the life of me find out what causes this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well - the culprit is React-Native.

The hint was this obscure line that appears on the Gradle console:

> google-services plugin could not detect any version for
>   com.google.android.gms or com.google.firebase, default version: 9.0.0
>   will be used.

The fix? Force the RN library project to link with the correct Firebase version, by adding the following line to its build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
```

And thus:

[image]

As a side-note, this issue has triggered me to look deeper into gradle dependency management. I've written an [extensive post about resolving common dependency issues](http://www.devsbedevin.com/android-understanding-gradle-dependencies-and-resolving-conflicts/).

Comment: i had a different issue, but this answer did the trick :) 

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/api/zza.class

Comment: I had the same problem, but when I added firebase-core version 10.0.1, I was getting: `com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/api/zze.class`
Rolling the version back to 9.2.1 fixed it. Thank you for your post!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use both the plugins in the build.gradle file
so remove the one Google Play Services plugin, like

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
```

So remove both of one library and then add

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // It is not include NOTICE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // It is not include LICENSE file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using this in app/build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
```

The error when I was trying to generate a Signed APK was:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/firebase/FirebaseApiNotAvailableException.class
```

I modified app/build.gradle by removing the two lines I mentioned above and using this instead:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
```

Of course "play-services" is the full bundle and not an optimized way to do this. It would be best to specify the specific services that are required (read [Does "play-services:9.8.0" include "play-services-location:9.8.0"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123539/does-play-services9-8-0-include-play-services-location9-8-0)), but for now it fixes the error in my case.

Answer (score 0):

[java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/firebase/iid/zzb.class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44648522/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-com-google-firebase-iid-zzb-class)

follow this its work .remove your current google play service dependency and go to file in android Studio select module setting and the select dependency tab now click on + icon and select lib dependency after that search your play service in studio and add it