# duplicate entry: com/google/firebase/iid/zzc.class

Tags: java, android, windows, firebase, android-studio

when i try to build a project on android studio 3.0.1 I got this error.

```
- Error:Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
- Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
- Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
- Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
- FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> What went wrong:
Execution failed for task':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'
.com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/firebase/iid/zzc.class
```

Some info about the project:

> - compileSdkVersion: 26
> - buildToolsVersion: 26.0.1
> - minSdkVersion: 15
> - targetSdkVersion: 24
> - classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
> - com.google.firebase:firebase : 12.0.1
> - android studio: 3.0.1

here is the build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

ext {
    supportlib_version = '26.1.0'
    gps_version = '11.2.0'
}

//Ensure that all dependencies use the same version of the Android Support library
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion "$supportlib_version"
            }
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion "$gps_version"
            }
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

> and build.gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    configurations {
        all*.exclude module: 'android.support.v4'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.hamkaret.patoghfarhang'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        multiDexEnabled true
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }

        //Optionally configure your OneSignal IDs below
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          : "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id               : "",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: ""]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    jcenter();
}

dependencies {
    compile 'co.ronash.android:pushe-base:1.4.3'
    compile 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.0.3'
    //TV
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.3'
    //TV & Radio
    compile 'com.cleveroad:audiovisualization:1.0.0'
    //Radio
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    //WC
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
    //WC
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.5,4.0.0)'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.booking:rtlviewpager:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.apg-mobile:android-round-textview:v0.0.3'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.0'
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportlib_version"
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportlib_version') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
    }
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportlib_version"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$supportlib_version"
    //compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportlib_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:$supportlib_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-media-compat:$supportlib_version"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$gps_version"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$gps_version"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$gps_version"
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

Comment: see : https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-firestack/issues/300 or see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38595171/duplicate-entry-com-google-firebase-firebaseapinotavailableexception-class

Comment: Have you tried to move `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end of the other build.gradle file and update all depdendencies to the last versions?